# How do I train a toddler to bite and chew food?

Tags: food, eating

My child is 2 years 8 months and he doesn't chew and bite food.

He eats porridge and drinks milk.

The solid food he will accept is a cheese tart, but he doesn't bite it, just swallows it. He also only likes the inner cheese and eats it off of a spoon. 
How do I train him to bite and chew food?

He always pushes solid food away.

Comment: Have you discussed this with a medical professional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do these steps(For parents):

- Find their favorite food, and try to make them a little solid but as much tasty as possible.
- Now sit near them and try to eat with different angle and make a reaction that it is very tasty
- After this wait for their reaction and see what they do.

Try these steps frequently so that your baby will try to chew. If these steps do not produce results then consult with your doctor.

Comment: What do you mean for try to eat with different angle? Do you mean put the food in his mouth in different place, right, middle and left?

Comment: Not I mean, It means that you have to put in your mouth and chew differently so when your child observes these type of activity, may be it will be start chew

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a solvable problem to me. However, it can be for reasons that I cannot 'diagnose' over the internet. So, I suggest you talk to your child's doctor and also consider a speech pathologist. They are biting and chewing experts. I understand it isn't about speech.

Comment: I have discussed this to doctor. He said it was natural behavior. Can't help. Speech pathologist said it might cause muscles around face is not strong enough.

Comment: Your doctor is an idiot.  Speech and/or occupational therapy may be required.  My child sees both for her eating aversion and it has greatly helped.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no medical reason for him doing so (have that checked), lead by example and really, really enjoy chewing easily chewable food. Might look silly to adults, but imitation is a strong lever. And you might even have a blast doing it if silly is funny to you.

Do it with food that he likes if it is mashed so that taste is not the problem.

Worst that can happen is that you'll make both of you laugh. Try it for a week and see what influences him.