# 15 month swallows everything without chewing

Tags: toddler, eating

my 15 month old daughter swallows everything she can without chewing. if only the morsel is hard only then, she would chew it.

How shall i teach her to chew before swallowing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/27973/30519).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a phase common to many kids and you should not be worried about it.

It's very important that you stay calm, relaxed and patient all the time.

What we did (which was successfully) was to:

1. Show our daughter how to chew while saying her "you should chew, how we do";
2. Start giving food that can be swallowed without chewing, alternative with some that must and that you can hold on your hands;

I would suggest to optionally look at [this page](http://www.livestrong.com/article/528303-how-to-get-toddlers-to-start-chewing-their-food/) which has good suggestions.